# how would you count the number of elements that are true in vector?

Tags: r

`PDF=Fr(r)=1/(1+r)^2` and `Rsample=Xsample/Ysample` where X,Y are independent exponential distributions with rate = 0.001.xsample=100 values stored in x,ysample=100 values stored in y.

Find the CDF FR(r) corresponding to the PDF and evaluate this at r ∈{0.1,0.2,0.25,0.5,1,2,4,5,10}. Find the proportions of values in R-sample less than each of these values of r and plot the proportions against FR(0.1), FR(0.2), ... ,FR(5),FR(10). What does this plot show?

I know that the CDF is the integral of the pdf but wouldn't this give me negative values of r.also for the proportions section how would you count the number of elements that are true, that is the number of elements for which R-sample is less than each element of r.

```
r=c(0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,1,2,4,5,10)
prop=c(1:9)
for(i in 1:9)
{
x=Rsample<r[i]
prop[i]=c(TRUE,FALSE)
}
sum(prop[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a few different errors here. The solution should look something like this.

Start by defining your variables and drawing your samples from the exponential distribution using `rexp(100, 0.001)`:

```r
r <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 10)

set.seed(69) # Make random sample reproducible
x <- rexp(100, 0.001) # 100 random samples from exponential distribution
y <- rexp(100, 0.001) # 100 random samples from exponential distribution

Rsample <- x/y
```

The tricky part is getting the proportion of `Rsample` that is less than each value of `r`. For this we can use `sapply` instead of a loop.

```r
props <- sapply(r, function(x) length(which(Rsample < x))/length(Rsample))
```

We get the cdf from the pdf by integrating (not shown):

```
cdf_at_r <- 1/(-r-1)  # Integral of 1/(1+r)^2 at above values of r
```

And we can see what happens when we plot the proportions that are less than the sample against the cdf:

```r
plot(cdf_at_r, props)

# What do we notice?
lines(c(-1, 0), c(0, 1), lty = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `prop <-  colMeans(outer(Rsample,r,"<"))` or even `prop<- sapply(r,function(x)mean(Rsample<x))`

Comment: @Onyambu thanks. These are both more concise (and more efficient) ways of doing it, but since this is obviously a homework question from an R noob, I thought I was already stretching it a bit using `sapply`!

Comment: I still used `sapply` only that I reduced the many computation within it. `mean(Rsample<x)` should be the anonymous function. one should know that the mean of a logical vector is the proportion itself

Comment: @Onyambu I know, I mean I put the computations in so the OP could understand it better. I didn't want to have to explain implicit conversions of Boolean to integer etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can count the number of elements for which R-sample is less than each element of r:

```
r=c(0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,1,2,4,5,10)
prop=c(1:9)
less = 0;
for(i in 1:9)
{
    if (Rsample<r[i]) {
        less = less + 1
    }
}
sum(prop[i])
less
```

Comment: what you have done could be depicted as `sum(Rsamlpe<r)` the question is what is `Rsample`?

Comment: @Onyambu it is described in the question, but it took me a while to figure out that's what the OP meant.